# How do I create an array in MATLAB by applying a function to the index of each element?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am looking for something like [`matrix(m, n, f)`, but for MATLAB rather than MuPAD, and for arrays rather than matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/matrix.html#stdlib-matrix-ex5).  That is, I'm looking for a(n efficient) way of doing this without for-loops:

```
ret = zeros(m, n);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        ret(i, j) = some_function([i, j]);
    end
end
```

Comment: If you can modify `some_function()`, you can just change the source code to make it work with array. Or try http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html

Comment: Good point. For that matter, is `some_function` already vectorized to work on arrays? Do you just need a way of efficiently constructing the `[i, j]` inputs over `1:m` and `1:n`? (e.g. `[is, js] = ind2sub([m n], 1:(m*n))`) Or is this about taking a function that only takes scalar inputs, and expanding its behavior? Very different answers for the two cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), and [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
m = 5; n = 5;                     %// matrix size
f   = @(i,j) i*j;                 %// anonymous function to apply to each array element
ret = bsxfun(f,(1:m)',1:n);       %'//apply bsxfun and get output
```

---

Output example:

```
ret =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2     4     6     8    10
     3     6     9    12    15
     4     8    12    16    20
     5    10    15    20    25
```

Comment: +1. Should prob note that OP did say "efficient", and this and other applicative techniques will perform about the same as for loops, since the overhead is in the repeated function call itself.

Comment: @AndrewJanke I've run a few tests and the `bsxfun` method seems to perform faster than `for` loops if the arrays are fairly large (`m,n > 1000`).

Comment: @eigenchris I have noticed the same, that in the recent MATLAB versions,  even the anonymous  functions with bsxfun are catching up with the built-ins.

Comment: Good to know. Seems I'm behind on the state of Matlab performance.

Comment: @AndrewJanke you made a good point... and in the case of 100x100 matrices the peformance is comparable to loops.